# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un nodo dada la posición en una lista doblemente enlazada en C?

Tags: c, lista, estructuras-de-datos

He estado intentando agregar un nodo dada la posición, pero no logro que se agregue en la primera posición.
Sin embargo sí es posible agregar un nodo en cualquiera de las posiciones posteriores.

También me gustaría evitar añadir el nodo cuando introduzco una posición demasiado grande.
Si tengo agregados 3 nodos y quiero agregarlo en la 4ª posicion (al final), sí lo añade correctamente.
Pero también lo agrega introduzco el numero 7 como posición.
Esto es un error ya que solo existen 3 nodos, no 6.
Por su atención, gracias.

Esta es mi función:

```c
void InsertarNodoN(int n, NODO *lista, CONTACTO *cnt)
{
   int posicion = 0;
   NODO * newn;
   NODO * aux;
   newn = crearn(cnt);
   if ((lista->sig == NULL) && (lista->ant == NULL))
   {
      lista->sig = (NODO*) newn;
      lista->ant = (NODO*) newn;
   }
   else
   {
      aux = (NODO*) lista->sig;
      while (((n - 2) > posicion) && (aux->sig != NULL))
      {
         aux = (NODO*) aux->sig;
         n++;
      }

      //aux contiene la direccion del ultimo nodo.
      newn->sig = aux->sig;
      aux->sig = (struct NODO *) newn;
      newn->ant = (struct NODO *) aux;
      lista->ant = (struct NODO *) newn;
   }

   printf("\nContacto agregado.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin el código completo es difícil entender cómo está la lista doblemente enlazada, pero con lo que proporcionaste solo se puede suponer una hipótesis:

No era necesario hacer la conversión de tipo (NODO*) porque newn ya es del tipo NODO*.

Dentro del bucle while en el else, la variable n se incrementa en lugar de posicionar, esto causará un bucle infinito.
En la condición ((n - 2) > posicion) debería ser (posicion < (n - 2)), se debería verificar si la posición actual es menor que (n - 2).

Para agregar un nodo en la primera posición, la posición n debe ser igual a 0 y la verificación de si la lista está vacía es incorrecta.

Sin el código completo para entender, intenté suponer cómo estaría la estructura completa y llegué a esta conclusión, la corrección se hizo en las partes que mencioné.

El código completo en mi interpretación del problema y la solución quedó de la siguiente manera para la lista doblemente enlazada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct {
    char nombre[20];
    int edad;
} CONTACTO;

typedef struct NODO {
    CONTACTO* contacto;
    struct NODO* sig;
    struct NODO* ant;
} NODO;

NODO* crearn(CONTACTO* cnt) {
    NODO* nodo = (NODO*)malloc(sizeof(NODO));
    nodo->contacto = cnt;
    nodo->sig = NULL;
    nodo->ant = NULL;
    return nodo;
}

void InsertarNodoN(int n, NODO** lista, CONTACTO* cnt) {
    NODO* newn = crearn(cnt);

    if (*lista == NULL) {
        *lista = newn;
        newn->sig = newn;
        newn->ant = newn;
        return;
    }

    if (n <= 0) {
        newn->sig = *lista;
        newn->ant = (*lista)->ant;
        (*lista)->ant->sig = newn;
        (*lista)->ant = newn;
        *lista = newn; //actualiza la lista para apuntar al nuevo nodo
        return;
    }

    int posicion = 0;
    NODO* aux = *lista;

    while (posicion < (n - 1) && aux->sig != *lista) {
        aux = aux->sig;
        posicion++;
    }

    newn->sig = aux->sig;
    newn->ant = aux;
    aux->sig->ant = newn;
    aux->sig = newn;

    printf("\nContacto agregado.\n");
}

void imprimirLista(NODO* lista) {
    if (lista == NULL) {
        printf("La lista está vacía!!!");
        return;
    }

    NODO* aux = lista;

    do {
        printf("nombre:  %s ", aux->contacto->nombre);
        printf("edad: %d\n", aux->contacto->edad);
        aux = aux->sig;
    } while (aux != lista);
}



int main(void) {
    NODO* lista = NULL;

    CONTACTO c1 = {"Sasuke Uchiha", 20};
    CONTACTO c2 = {"Saitama", 13};
    CONTACTO c3 = {"Aki Hayakawa", 37};

    InsertarNodoN(2, &lista, &c1);
    InsertarNodoN(33, &lista, &c2);
    InsertarNodoN(0, &lista, &c3); //Añadir en primera posición
    imprimirLista(lista);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: El primer párrafo podría ser un comentario. Recuerda que es mejor dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación.